# opencv library project sowing many errors

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

After importing opencv-android-sdk  library project into workspace, it shows so many errors.
I tried following tutorial

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

But i am not getting

....\sdk\java

under Library section as picture showing in step 2 in tutorial.
(Sorry I am allowed to post image here.)

Is there any problem with my java.
I am using Ubuntu 13.04 with Eclipse Version: 3.8.1 and OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Check your project build properties, change the OpenCV import path to the correct one (make sure the path of opencv relative to your application matches what you place in import path).